# how to access dynamic textbox (which is on stage) to external actionscript file (.as)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to make a game similar to mario using flash. I have an external file called Enemy.as. and in this file, I want to get the number of enemies killed and display it in the textbox (which is on stage). but im facing the #1009 error.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
    var player:MovieClip;
    public var enemyKilled:int;

    public function Enemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int)
    {
        // constructor code
        x = xLocation;
        y = yLocation;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Enemyloop);
    }

    public function Enemyloop(e:Event):void
    {
        /*//the looping code goes here
        player = MovieClip(root).player;
        if(this.hitTestObject(player))
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Enemyloop);
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }*/
    }

    public function removeSelf():void
    {
        trace("remove self");
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Enemyloop); //stop the loop
        this.parent.removeChild(this); //tell this object's "parent object" to remove this object
        enemyKilled++;
        MovieClip(root).tbxEnemy.text = ("enemyKilled: " + enemyKilled.toString());
    }

}
```

}

[This is the error message:

remove self

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Enemy/removeSelf()
    at Ass3_fla::MainTimeline/loop() [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nin0z.png)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `enemiesKilled:uint` should be static.
Otherwise every `Enemy` is counting up a different (his own) variable.
If the variable is static, there will be only one variable for the class aka all the objects derived from it.
(Changing the name and type is not necessary, just what I would do personally)

Your `Enemy` class is doing too much.
It shouldn't be the concern of your `Enemy` to set some `Textfield`'s `.text` property. With your current code, your `Enemy` class relies on this very specify `Textfield` to exist. If you change that `Textfield` your code breaks silently. (because you are casting root to dynamic `MovieClip` class, which throws compile time checks out of the window)

**Instead, use Events.**

Instead of manipulating some `Textfield` elsewhere in your project, dispatch an `Event`.
This allows you to place the functionality of what should happen when an `Enemy` dies outside of the `Enemy` class, which makes sense, because the `Textfield` isn't even in your `Enemy` class.

dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));

which allows you to listen for this `Event` on the main time line, where your enemies are created:

```
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy (); // this only works if you provide default values for your constructor parameters which I highly recommend doing
enemy.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onEnemyDeath, false, 0, true);

function onEnemyDeath (e:Event):void
{
    tbxEnemy.text = "Number of enemies killed: " + Enemy.enemiesKilled.toString();
}
```

You could do anything upon the death of an `Enemy` without ever touching that class again stuffing more functionality into it that doesn't belong there.

Also, the `root` property is `null` if the `DisplayObject` has no `parent`.